# iOS simulator not displaying objects correctly - xcode 4.5.2 and iOS simulator 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, simulator

[image]

As you can see in the picture i uploaded, this is the basically the problem.

I did not even write any code yet, just have a basic view controller with 2 buttons and a label on it...it is displayed in a certain way in my story board (the way i want), but when it is run it is displayed incorrectly as you can see in the iOS simulator. Any reason to why this is happening or how to correct it?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your story board is in iPhone 5 (4 inch) layout and the simulator running in 3.7 inch mode. You can toggle the settings in storyboard editor to see how it will look in both modes and make sure you set up your positioning rules so it works dynamically for both.

Comment: thanks for the quick resposne trapper! simple and worked (new to this version of xcode)